# Issue when using .htaccess file to hide .php extension

Tags: .htaccess, url, file-extension, trailing-slash

I have the following .htaccess file on my website for removing extensions:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

This works perfectly on localhost, however, when I upload the file to GoDaddy and try to visit a URL, say `mysite.com/page`, Google Chrome automatically adds a trailing slash to the URL (just on the website, not on localhost). I'm assuming this causes the site to assume that `page` is a folder/directory and not a file? Is this what's happening? If so, what would be the best way to tackle the issue? Should I add to my .htaccess to automatically remove trailing slashes, or should I maybe have each page as a directory each with an `index.php`? What's the most efficient method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to enforce no trailing slash if it is not a folder.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R]
```